# How should I structure this application?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am writing an iPhone application which requires the user to enter their mobile no and pin code and press an accept button before they continue into the application.

Previously I had (each view is in a different Xib)

AppDelegate - if {registered add load RootView (which is main view) into NavigationController} else {load RegistrationView subview}

But then when the RegistrationView loaded it would appear under the status bar, also I then dont know how to load the main app with a nav bar after registration, on load it works fine but from the reg page it loads without the nav bar

Then I tried

AppDelegate - if {registered add load RootView (which is reg view) in NavigationController} else {load RootView and then immediately push HomeView}

But then the UINavigationController doesnt appear to work on the main page

What would be the best way to implement this? Should I put both home pages in the same xib?

Comment: What do you mean by "status bar"? The only status bar on the iPhone is at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app I get users to enter their username and password in a modal view:

```
[navigationController presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
```

I call this in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method of the app delegate. This gets called the first time the program is launched. The same dialog is displayed on authentication failure.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary solution

AppDelegate - if registered {add load RootView (which is main view) into NavigationController} else {add load RootView (which is main view) into NavigationController and load RegistrationView as subview}

RegistrationView - on registration hide reg subview